# How can I sharpen the lines in a scanned diagram?

Tags: scanning

I have a black-and-white diagram (floor plans) scanned from a printout. It's mostly OK, but some of the lines are visibly faded or blurred in places, so it "looks" scanned.

I've tried various options in Paint.NET so far without any success. I could download any free software that would do the job. I could probably get access to Photoshop as well (not sure which version), but I wouldn't even know where to start with that.

**Is there an easy way to make them into clear, sharp lines?**

Comment: One thing though; you say 'black-and-white diagram (floor plan)' but I suppose you meant something like 'blueprint' (instead of diagram)? Otherwise I might be understanding the question wrong.

Comment: Can you post a sample image?

Comment: Thanks, poepje! I ended up getting a clean digital copy of the image in the end, but it's good to know what to try if I ever have to do this again.

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop you could try ***Filters > Sharpen > Sharpen*** Edges. Along with that, to make it a little more clear, go to ***Image > Adjustments > Levels..*** and play with that to remove blurry edges and darkening the sharp lines.

Answer (score 0):

I notices that with a grayscale images is useful:

- **Color > Curves**, usually an S curve, similar to increase contrast. Touch on gray points on image to choose what levels you will convert to white/black.
- **Filter > Enhance > Unsharp Mask...** and play with values
- **Filter > Enhance > NL Filter...** and play with values